# What does it mean for an algorithm to not resample points?

Tags: information-theory

The No Free Lunch theorems for search and optimization demonstrate that for search/optimization problems in a limited search space, where the points being searched through are not resampled, the performance of any two given search algorithms over all possible problems is the same.

> No Free Lunch for Search/Optimization

> The no free lunch theorem for search and optimization (Wolpert and Macready 1997) applies to finite spaces and algorithms that do not resample points. All algorithms that search for an extremum of a cost function perform exactly the same when averaged over all possible cost functions. So, for any search/optimization algorithm, any elevated performance over one class of problems is exactly paid for in performance over another class.

I don't understand the meaning of *algorithms that do not resample points*.

1. What can be an example of an algorithm that does not resample points and one that does resample points?
2. Why does the theorem not apply to algorithms that implement resampling of points?

Comment: Resampling increases the size of the search space by creating new points.